# XML parsing with DOM parser

Tags: java, xml-parsing

In my app I am trying to parse XML file using DOM parser. If parsing is successful then the file is moved to success directory else to error directory.next the files are deleted from source directory

The problem is, when ever some ill formed XML file (ex: Xml document missing end tags) exception is throws along with the following error message.

"**The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**"

Due to this the file is not deleted from source directory.

```
public  class XMLLoader extends Thread {
boolean success =false;
public XMLLoader(SoapConnection con, String xmlPath) {

    try {
        System.out.println("Laoding the XML...");
        File file = new File(xmlPath);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(file);
        String xmlString = null;

        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);
        xmlString = writer.toString();
        InboundCaseXmlResponse cResponse = con.LoadXmlCase(xmlString);
        System.out.println("SOAP Response == "+cResponse);
        if(cResponse.getHasErrors()== false)
        {
            success = true; 
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }


}
public boolean getStatus()
{
    return success;
}
```

}

Comment: You need to catch the exception and in catch you need to move xml to error folder. Update your code in question.

Comment: You haven't indicated any language or specific technology, so all we could do is guess. It's likely that, in the exceptional case, something is not being cleaned up in a timely fashion. This could probably be fixed with, for example, judicious use of `finally` blocks or `using` clauses, if your language supports them.

Comment: hi vels4j, I have updated the question with the code.thanks

Comment: hi Damien_The_Unbeliever, i am working with java.according to the error message some process is still working on the file, so i guess stoping the process will help but have no idea on how to do that.Thanks

Comment: catch (Exception e) { success=false;)

Comment: Does your thread terminates?

Comment: Also how about `success = cResponse.getHasErrors()`?

Comment: hi rlegendi, i looked for all available threads but i found none matching the context. Also the success = cResponse.getHasErrors(); code works on if their are errors like "unable to upsert" or "like required field missing". i am trying to insert records in SFDC through the process.

Comment: hi vels4j, i tried it but with no result. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

i just found a simle way..

```
private static boolean loadXml(SoapConnection con, String xmlPath) {
    boolean success =false;
    FileInputStream file=null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Loading the XML...");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        file = new FileInputStream(xmlPath);
        Document document = builder.parse(file);
        System.out.println(document.hasChildNodes());
        String xmlString = null;            
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);
        xmlString = writer.toString();
        InboundCaseXmlResponse cResponse = con.LoadXmlCase(xmlString);
        System.out.println("SOAP Response == "+cResponse);
        if(cResponse.getHasErrors()== false)
        {
            success = true; 
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        try{
        file.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();    
        }

        }

    return success;
}
```